# stormpath error If you do not specify a \'requestAuthenticator\' field, y

Tags: authentication, express, stormpath

I'm getting the error specified above when trying to build a express-stormpath app. I'll list the applicable code:

```
  Error: If you do not specify a 'requestAuthenticator' field, you must specify an ApiKey.
         at Object.getAuthenticator (d:\dev\git-repos\bps\VolumeGridDataEntry\node_modules\express-    stormpath\node_modules\stormpath\lib\authc\index.js:24:11)
         at new RequestExecutor (d:\dev\git-repos\bps\VolumeGridDataEntry\node_modules\express-stormpath\node_modules\stormpath\lib\ds\RequestExecutor.js:37:37)
          at new DataStore (d:\dev\git-repos\bps\VolumeGridDataEntry\node_modules\express-stormpath\node_modules\stormpath\lib\ds\DataStore.js:46:52)
          at new Client (d:\dev\git-repos\bps\VolumeGridDataEntry\node_modules\express-stormpath\node_modules\stormpath\lib\Client.js:8:21)
         at d:\dev\git-repos\bps\VolumeGridDataEntry\node_modules\express-stormpath\lib\stormpath.js:60:36
         at d:\dev\git-repos\bps\VolumeGridDataEntry\node_modules\express-stormpath\node_modules\stormpath\lib\authc\ApiKeyLoader.js:14:14
         at d:\dev\git-repos\bps\VolumeGridDataEntry\node_modules\express-stormpath\node_modules\stormpath\node_modules\properties-parser\index.js:348:20
         at fs.js:208:20
         at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
```

[Updated] server.js

```
  var express = require('express'),
      session = require('express-session'),
      crypto = require('crypto'),
      formidable = require('formidable'),
      path = require('path'),
      favicon = require('serve-favicon'),
      logger = require('morgan'),
      cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      index = require('./routes/index'),
      users = require('./routes/users'),
      stormpath = require('express-stormpath'),
      config = require('./config/credentials.js'),
      app = express();

  function hashPwd(pwd) {
    return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(pwd).digest('base64').toString();
  }

  // view engine setup
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


 app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
    apiKeyFile: config.stormpathapi.apiKeyFile,
    application: config.stormpathapi.application,
    secretKey: config.stormpathapi.secretKey,
    sessionDuration: 1000 * 60 * 30
 }));

 // domains for better error handling
 app.use(function(req, res, next){
    // create a domain for this request
    var domain = require('domain').create();
    // handle errors on this domain
    domain.on('error', function(err){
       console.error('DOMAIN ERROR CAUGHT\n', err.stack);
       try {
           // failsafe shutdown in 5 seconds
           setTimeout(function(){
              console.error('Failsafe shutdown.');
              process.exit(1);
            }, 5000);

           // stop taking new requests
           server.close();

           try {
               // attempt to use Express error route
               next(err);
            } catch(error){
              // if Express error route failed, try
              // plain Node response
              console.error('Express error mechanism failed.\n', error.stack);
              res.statusCode = 500;
              res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
              res.end('Server error.');
            }
        } catch(error){
           console.error('Unable to send 500 response.\n', error.stack);
        }
    });

     // add the request and response objects to the domain
     domain.add(req);
     domain.add(res);

     // execute the rest of the request chain in the domain
     domain.run(next);
   });

   // cross-site request forgery protection
   app.use(require('csurf')());

   app.use(function(req, res, next){
      res.locals._csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
      next();
    });

    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

    //name: cookie_name,
    //store: sessionStore, // connect-mongo session store
    app.use(session({
        secret: config.cookieSecret,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true
     }));

     app.use('/', index);
     app.use('/users', users);

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
         var err = new Error('Not Found');
         err.status = 404;
        next(err);
    });

    // error handlers

    // development error handler
    // will print stacktrace
    if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
       app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
       res.status(err.status || 500);
       res.render('error', {
           message: err.message,
           error: err
        });
     });
   }

  // production error handler
  // no stacktraces leaked to user
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error', {
          message: err.message,
          error: {}
      });
   });


  module.exports = app;
```

route index.js

```
  var express = require('express'),
      stormpath = require('express-stormpath'),
      router = express.Router();

  router.get('/', stormpath.groupsRequired(['dataentry']), function(req, res) {
     res.render('index', { title: 'Volume Grid Data Entry' });
  });

 module.exports = router;
```

Initially the route signature was this but that didn't work either. I will need the ability in the future to base page security on groups...so, I'm not sure if I should use loginRequired or groupsRequired or both :-/

```
  router.get('/', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res) {
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code looks correct -- but where is your `app.use(require('./index'));` code? That will be necessary after the `app.use(stormpath.init(...))` stuff above =)

NOTE: I'm the author of the express-stormpath library.

EDIT: Here's a full example:

```
var express = require('express'),
    stormpath = require('express-stormpath'),
    router = express.Router();

var app = express();

router.get('/', stormpath.groupsRequired(['dataentry']), function(req, res) {
 res.render('index', { title: 'Volume Grid Data Entry' });
});

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for replying @rdegges. I updated the question with the route inclusion. I believe my code and yours is the same except that I have the route defined in another file but I do pull it in after the stormpath init. I'll look again later this evening. Thank you!

Comment: P.S. @rdegges also it could be some other middleware mucking things up. I'll post the full server.js later this evening. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Ok, still getting the error. I'm guessing it is one of the other middlewares. I'll start by commenting them all out except stormpath's then add in one by one @rdegges

Comment: Ugh, it was a case of stupid programmer error. I didn't escape the path (Windows) to the apiKey file properly. Sorry @rdegges & thanks !!!!

Comment: Ah! Glad it is working. Just woke up and saw your replies -- sorry about that!